# Is it possible to implement (without macros) an implicit zip/unzip in Scala to achieve a sneaky fluent or lazy pattern?

Tags: scala

### Edit2

Okay, so maybe I should parse out two desires here.

I had in mind that when it came time to get to the `setSendTimeout(0)` part, I would be using something like `implicitly[Socket]`.

```
new ZContext(1) {
   createSocket(ZMQ.PUB).setSendTimeout(0).//RATS!
}
```

I also had in mind a more generic approach to it, that would be (in pseudo code terms):

1. This is how you wrap a reference of `T` at a point in time without copying it, so that moving forward, you can tease out state of the reference after potential state changes from the value of whatever expression used it.
2. If it could be thought of as a chain of `map` `map` `map` s from `T` to where ever it ended up, then it is easy to append / apply a value onto it - just `map` again...

This is the motivating example.

```
  override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic = new GraphStageLogic(shape) {
    logger.info("Initializing ZMQ context.")
    val context = new ZContext(1)
    logger.info(s"Binding PUB socket to ${endpoint}")
    val socket = {
      val s = context.createSocket(ZMQ.PUB)
      s.setSendTimeOut(0)
      s.bind(endpoint)
      s
    }
```

Look at `socket` down there. For some reason that feels uglier than it needs to be to me, but is a consequence of the fact that `setters` don't return stuff like `setSendTimeOut`.

I would normally try to improve it as follows:

```
new ZContext(1) {
   createSocket(ZMQ.PUB).setSendTimeout(0).//RATS!
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a version of @Dima's answer. Again the setup:

```
trait Instance {
  def createPort(): Port
}

trait Port {
  def makeSpecial(): Unit
  def bindTo(address: Any): Unit
}

trait Provider {
  def getTheInstance(i: Int): Instance
}
```

Now the trick:

```
implicit class InstanceOps(i: Instance) {
  def withCreatePort(fun: (Unit => Port) => Any): Port = {
    val res = i.createPort()
    fun(_ => res)
    res
  }
}
```

And if you add an `implicit` modifier to the argument of the function passed into `withCreatePort`, you "import" the implicit conversion:

```
trait ConnectTest extends Provider {
  getTheInstance(2).withCreatePort { implicit p =>
    ().makeSpecial().bindTo("foo")
  }
}
```

This is potentially more dangerous, because you have an implicit conversion from `Unit` to `Port`, although it is locally encapsulated. This is generic because `Connect` is generic.

This trick is perhaps too clever and difficult to understand by some outside standing person reading your code.

Comment: Don't they do exactly this in Akka`s `GraphDSL` building calls?

Comment: `  val flow = GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
    val in =   ... , val out =   ...
    FlowShape(in out)
  }`

Comment: Not familiar with Akka, but it looks different. Instead of an implicit conversion (function) you simply have an implicit context (`builder`; value) that will be consumed by the constructors `FlowShape(...)` etc. This is more clean but doesn't apply to your case where the API is given.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create two wrappers, one giving you `withCreatePort`, the other giving you variants of the port method that return `this`:

```
trait Instance {
  def createPort(): Port
}

trait Port {
  def makeSpecial(): Unit
  def bindTo(address: Any): Unit
}

class PortOps(p: Port) {
  def makeSpecial()       : this.type = { p.makeSpecial()  ; this }
  def bindTo(address: Any): this.type = { p.bindTo(address); this }
}

implicit class InstanceOps(i: Instance) {
  def withCreatePort[A](fun: PortOps => A): A = fun(new PortOps(i.createPort()))
}
```

Example:

```
trait Provider {
  def getTheInstance(i: Int): Instance
}

trait Plain extends Provider {
  val instance = getTheInstance(2)
  val port = instance.createPort()
  port.makeSpecial()
  port.bindTo("foo")
}

trait Rich extends Provider {
  getTheInstance(2).withCreatePort { p =>
    p.makeSpecial().bindTo("foo")
  }
}
```

The question is if the effort is worth it. You can also experiment with `import`:

```
trait Import extends Provider {
  val instance = getTheInstance(2)
  val port = instance.createPort()
  locally {
    import port._
    makeSpecial(); bindTo("foo")
  }
}
```

Comment: Now... can this be genericized? That's kind of the other part of the question I didn't spell out

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos No, not without macros. See my edit with the import, though.

Comment: Let me check out the `locally` example you provided... I updated my example with the exact motivation to get rid of the long-winded return value

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where you are going with this `Zipped` thingy ... But what you described in the beginning of your question (assuming that `port` in the end of that snippet is a typo, and you really meant to return `instance`) can be done with something like this:

```
object Taps {
  implicit class Tap[T](t: T) extends Anyval {
    def tap(f: T => Unit) = { f(t); t }
  }
}
```

Then you can write:

```
import Taps._
val instance = getTheInstance(2).tap { 
   _.createPort
   .makeSpecial
   .bindTo(...)
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Your answer is getting close to what I am thinking. Forget the specifics of my example... its really more about NOT LOSING a type due to a method being called that returns a Unit. Let me update my example real fast.

Comment: Well, with this,  you could do: `context.createSocket(ZMQ.PUB).tap(_.setSendTimeOut(0)).tap(_.bind(endpoint))`. Or `socket.tap { s => s.setSendTimeout(0); s.bind(endpoint) }`

Comment: This seems basically right, I will play with it for a bit